# MVC3 is it possible to return a view with an achor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, anchor

If I have a controller action that returns a simple view

`return View("Index");`

Is there some way I could return with the browser being sent to /#tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done on the client before invoking the action that will return the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "MyAction", "MyController", null, null, "tab", null, null)
```

Comment: This is from a form submission, where there are errors so the view is returned directly instead of completing the PGR chain. The view is using jQuery UI tabs, so the user gets dropped onto the default tab without actually seeing the error messages until they click the right tab.

Comment: @Chris, you cannot modify the url from within a controller action if you do not redirect. The best way to achieve what you are trying to do is to do it on the client side. Register a startup javascript function which will execute immediately the view is returned in case of model error and which will set the `window.location.hash` property.